# How can I convert a .png file to .icns

Tags: conversion, png

What is the correct way of converting one or more .png files to .icns files?.

I've installed `icnsutils` but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to work with `png2icns`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
 png2icns file.icns file.png
```

The first one is the name you want your .icns file to have. The last one is the .png file you want to export as an icon.

**Important: Only convert the icons that match sizes icns supports:** (16x16, 32x32, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512 and 1024x1024 pixels)

Or you can use an online service: [iConvert Icons](http://iconverticons.com/)

Source: [Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/png2icns.1.html)

Comment: It complains about the size `Bad dimensions`. I just tried iConvert works fine however,I have to manually select the images one by one, I have to convert over 600 pngs :) .

Comment: Which are the dimensions you are trying to use? Apparently that error is thrown when the size is not supported. The [png2icns documentation](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libicns/0.5.8/png2icns_8c.html) says: **/* Only convert the icons that match sizes icns supports */** which as far as I know are: 16x16, 32x32, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512 and 1024x1024 pixels

Comment: Hmm they're 640x640 but I can resize them to 512 and try again, is there a way to batch convert them?

Comment: You can try using this software: [RedImages](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/04/redimages-simply-and-lightweight-batch-image-resizer-for-ubuntu-1.html)

Comment: Sorry, I mean batch convert the .png files to .icns

Comment: Sorry, not that I know.

Comment: To batch-convert image sizes use ImageMagick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304480/batch-resize-images-and-output-images-to-new-folder-with-imagemagick

Answer (score 1):

Since converting a PNG image into an ICNS file is very time consuming, I developed my own CLI to do it automatically and quickly. You can install the package using the node package manager (npm).

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-icns.

You just need to give it a PNG and it will do all the rest for you:

```bsh
$ mk-icns /path/to/pngFile.png /destination/directory
```

Please follow the documentation for more details

Here is a link to the node official website if you do not know what npm or node is: https://nodejs.org/en/